# Is there any way to place buttons at the menu bar of the form in lwuit

Tags: menu, command, lwuit

I have to set button at the bottom of screen. I am using lwuit(UI). Is there any way to place button in menu bar and I have set the command in menu bar but the command name is partially displayed why somebody help.
Thanks for your any appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `addCommand(new Command("Name"));` this should work. Commands will only take 50% of the screen in standard mode so if your text is longer the text of the command will be cropped. You can replace the `MenuBar` class but that is an advanced task so I suggest not going there.